# symfony2: Overriding DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler throws exception: "Authentication Success Handler did not return a Response."

Tags: symfony, events, authentication

My custom success handler has the following method:

```
function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
{
    // Do nothing for now
}
```

In my *security.yml* the `form_login` section contains:

```
...
default_target_path: bundle_app_homepage
always_use_default_target_path: true
success_handler: security.authentication.success_handler
```

If I remove the `success_handler` parameter, it redirects automatically to `bundle_app_homepage` as expected.

Now with my custom handler in place I get:

> Authentication Success Handler did not return a Response.

Even if I add `return null;` to the handler I get the same error. It seems pointless that I need to add a redirect to the handler if it's defined in security.yml, which is the only other option I can think of.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: Could you please explain why you override the `success_handler` to ... do nothing? What do you expect to happen? symfony doesn't know how to proceed if the `success_handler` is a dead-end.

Comment: I am doing something, but with an empty function I was able to ascertain the redirect behaviour wasn't due to any faulty code I had put in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at the default-handler's **[onAuthenticationSuccess()](https://github.com/symfony/Security/blob/master/Http/Authentication/DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler.php#L53)** method.

The method redirects to the configured target-path using the method `determinetargetUrl()`.

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
{
    return $this->httpUtils->createRedirectResponse($request, $this->determineTargetUrl($request));
}
```

If you clear the `onAuthenticationSuccess()` method ... the `default_target_path` just isn't used anymore.

The redirect is necessary to show the correct url in the browser after successful authentication.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I get this: `Notice: Undefined property: MyApp\AuthBundle\Other\AuthenticationSuccessHandler::$httpUtils` - currently I just have RouterInterface $router and EntityManager $em in the constructor. Do I need to add more arguments?

Comment: That's a different issue. just open a new question for it and I'll be happy to help out. Please consider upvoting/accepting my answer if it helped you with your inital question.

Comment: I have created a new question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24643929/symfony-authentication-success-handler-issues-httputils