# Symfony authentication success handler issues - httpUtils

Tags: symfony, authentication

I get this error: `Notice: Undefined property: MyApp\AuthBundle\Other\AuthenticationSuccessHandler::$httpUtils`

As a result of using this code in my login success handler:

```
public function onAuthenticationSuccess(Request $request, TokenInterface $token)
{
    return $this->httpUtils->createRedirectResponse($request, $this->determineTargetUrl($request));
}
```

I realise this is because I don't have an httpUtils property in my class. However I don't know how to inject it?

Currently I just have RouterInterface $router and EntityManager $em in the constructor. Do I need to add more arguments? Or update any YML files?

Answer (score 3):

You need to change your constructor to accept the `security.http_utils` service:

```
class LoginSuccessHandler ...
{

    protected $httpUtils;

    ...

    public function __construct(HttpUtils $httpUtils, ...)
    {
        $this->httpUtils = $httpUtils;
        $this->router = $router;
        $this->security = $security;
    }
```

Then update your services:

```
login_success_handler:
    class:  AppBundle\EventListener\LoginSuccessHandler
    arguments:  ["@security.http_utils", ... ]
    tags:
      - { name: 'monolog.logger', channel: 'security' }
```

I'd also recommend you extend `DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler` this will give you the `determineTargetUrl` method:

```
class LoginSuccessHandler extends DefaultAuthenticationSuccessHandler
{
    public function __construct(HttpUtils $httpUtils, ...)
    {
        parent::__construct($httpUtils);

        $this->router = $router;
        $this->security = $security;
    }

    // ...
```

}
Or you can copy it over to your class:

```
/**
 * Builds the target URL according to the defined options.
 *
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @return string
 */
protected function determineTargetUrl(Request $request)
{
    if ($this->options['always_use_default_target_path']) {
        return $this->options['default_target_path'];
    }

    if ($targetUrl = $request->get($this->options['target_path_parameter'], null, true)) {
        return $targetUrl;
    }

    if (null !== $this->providerKey && $targetUrl = $request->getSession()->get('_security.'.$this->providerKey.'.target_path')) {
        $request->getSession()->remove('_security.'.$this->providerKey.'.target_path');

        return $targetUrl;
    }

    if ($this->options['use_referer'] && ($targetUrl = $request->headers->get('Referer')) && $targetUrl !== $this->httpUtils->generateUri($request, $this->options['login_path'])) {
        return $targetUrl;
    }

    return $this->options['default_target_path'];
}
```

BTW. If you wondered where the http_utils service was its private:

```
$ php app/console container:debug --show-private | grep security.http_utils
```